# RabbitMQ Race conditions / Dependent messages

Tags: patterns-and-practices, message-queue

I'm currently working on a project, where we'll have to keep a local system in "sync" with a remote application.

For example if a new customer is created in the local application, this customer must also be created in the remote app - via a rest api - and the "remote" user id must be stored within the local app for further usage.

In order to get the initial sync running, we started calling the remote app directly when a user was created and waited for the response. This approach has many downsides: one of them is that the user has to wait for the remote system call to finish in order to continue his workflow.

So we are currently looking for alternatives to the initial approach and message brokers (i.e. RabbitMQ) could be the way to go.

I already did some research on RabbitMQ itself and also skipped through the [Enterprise Integration Pattern book](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com) but I'm failing to outline the following example workflow:

1.) An account is created in the local application (it must also be created in the remote application and the remote account id must also be stored in the local app)

2.) Directly after the account creation, a user for this account is created (it must also be created in the remote application and the remote user id must also be stored in the local app)

When performing these two steps async I cannot ensure that the company id from the remote system has already been synced back to the local app. So maybe I will not be able to attach the user to the company in the remote app ...

Is there any kind of pattern or some best practise approach to this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: You're considering the RabbitMQ for the backend, is that correct?

Comment: You have to be able to create a unique id without using the remote application, or to be able to use a temporary, recognizable internal id in the local app, and avoid further communication with the remote application until you receive back the id created there.

Comment: @DavidPacker Yes, we're considering using RabbitMQ for the backend.

Comment: @FrankHileman That was also one of our ideas. We could generate a uuid for the remote app - this would solve a lot of problems, but unfortunately the maintainers of the remote app are not going to change their api ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just by starting to use RabbitMQ your collaboration of the two systems will not suddenly feel smoother and more user-friendly. In fact, by plugging RabbitMQ into your system it's likely to bring even more problems.

And even then, your problem is not the API being synchronous, your problem is the client calling API synchronously and waiting for a response. This is the place where you should start looking first.

Your API can stay synchronous as it is, i.e. synchronously processing the request to create a new `User`/`Account`. On the client, ideally you would be looking at something like this:

1. User clicks on a `Save User` button.
2. A `User` entity is saved to a local database - very fast.
3. An `NewUserHasBeenSaved` event is dispatched to some message bus.
4. <sup>*async*</sup> A process manager listens to occurring events within the system, takes the `NewUserHasBeenSaved` event from the message queue and issues a new command `PersistNewUserToRemoteApi`.
5. <sup>*async*</sup> A command handler responsible for handling the `PersistNewUserToRemoteApi` command pulls out the `User` entity from local database and pushes it to the API - this operation could take somewhere between few ms up to a few minutes - depending on the network situation and/or size of the payload.
6. <sup>*async*</sup> Should remote API call be successful the local `User` entity is updated with remote id. On failure the `PersistNewUserToRemoteApi` is scheduled for retry - the strategy is up to you to decide, depends entirely on your specific case.
7. User inserts account information and click on a `Save Account` button.
8. An `Account` entity is saved to a local database being mapped to a local `User` entity (e.g. via a foreign key).
9. An `NewAccountHasBeenSaved` event is dispatched to some message bus.
10. Dialog for account creation is closed and user can proceed with additional operations.
11. <sup>*async*</sup> Just like in 4, process manager listens for events, takes the `NewAccountHasBeenSaved` event from the message queue and issues a new command `PersistNewAccountToRemoteApi`.
12. <sup>*async*</sup> A command handler for the `PersistNewAccountToRemoteApi` pulls out the local `Account` from local database and it's associated `User` entity. Then checks, whether the `User` already contains a remote id - i.e. whether it has already been persisted. If the `User` entity contains remote it the command handler issues a remote call to the API for the account, otherwise schedules the `PersistNewAccountToRemoteApi` for retry. Once again, the retry strategy depends on your own needs.

As you can see, some of the operations are marked as <sup>*async*</sup>, i.e. the execution order may not necessarily have to be the one I specified, but the actions could happen in the order of: 1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11, 12.

You also don't have to issue commands to send the entities to the remote API but do it directly in the process manager. Once again, depends on your needs.

What might interest you is the [Actor model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model), which should be possible to implement on the client side as well.

Comment: Thanks for the very detailled answer! You perfectly described the workflow - for me there was some general misunderstanding regarding the sheduling: I always thought about sheduling a "request" and not an event. The event is certainly  the better abstraction level. Netherless, I'm a little bit concerned about the retry strategy. This will not be trivial. The more I think about it, the more I like the idea from @FrankHileman that we will create a uuid in the local system and send it to the api. But you helped my a lot! Thanks.

Comment: @sl0815 about the retry logic you can easily create some sort of exponential timeframe logic in which call should be made, thats what we do in our betting company and it seems to be working judt fine